# Replacing a button to go a paid layout with a swiping motion

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, swipe

I am building an `app`. One of the features I have is a paid option in which the user has access to an additional layout.  Right now, the user can get there by clicking a button.  Instead, I would like to have a swiping motion- if the user swipes down, it will ask for permission for the paid layout.  If they do pay, when they swipe up, they can access the original layout.

Here is my main activity :

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText editText2;
        Button btn_purchase;
        ImageView imageView2;
        String skuId;
        SessionManager sessionManager;
        // create new Person
        private BillingClient mBillingClient;

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
            protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                sessionManager=new SessionManager(MainActivity.this);
                if(sessionManager.getPurchased()){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaidActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                btn_purchase=findViewById(R.id.btn_purchase);
            imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(MainActivity.this).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
                    if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK
                            && purchases != null) {
                        for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                            //TODO: Handle purchase
                            //        handlePurchase(purchase);
                            Log.e("Main", "handle Purchase ");
                            Log.e("MainAct", "onPurchasesUpdated() response: " + responseCode);
                            Log.e("dev", "successful purchase...");
                            String purchasedSku = purchase.getSku();
                            Log.e("dev", "Purchased SKU: " + purchasedSku);
                            String purchaseToken = purchase.getPurchaseToken();
                            sessionManager.savePurchased(true);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaidActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.USER_CANCELED) {
                        // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
                    } else {
                        // Handle any other error codes.
                    }
                }
            }).build();



            List<String> skuList = new ArrayList <> ();
            skuList.add("appsubscription2018");
            SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
            params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
            mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                    new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                            // Process the result.

                            if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                                Log.e("MainActivity", "onSkuDetailsResponse: success");
                                for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {

                                    Log.e("MainActivity", "products: "+skuDetailsList);
                                    String sku = skuDetails.getSku();
                                    skuId = skuDetails.getSku();
                                    String price = skuDetails.getPrice();
                                    if ("appsubscription2018 ".equals(sku)) {
                                        Log.e("MainActivity", "product is appsubscription2018 ");
                              //          mPremiumUpgradePrice = price;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });




            btn_purchase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
                            if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                                // The billing client is ready. You can query purchases here.
                                // The billing client is ready. You can query purchases here.
                                BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                        .setSku("appsubscription2018")
                                        .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
                                        .build();
                                int responseCode = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(MainActivity.this, flowParams);
                                if (responseCode != BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                                 Log.e("Main", "launchBillingFlow ok");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
                        }
                    });

                }
            });


    imageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (checkFilePermission(MainActivity.this)){
                    getPhoto();
                }
        }
    });






            }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


            if (requestCode ==1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);

                    imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        public static boolean checkFilePermission(final Context context) {
            int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if(currentAPIVersion>= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                        alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                        alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                    }
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void getPhoto() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            if (requestCode ==1){
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);{
                    getPhoto();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Jesse, and welcome to the site.  As it stands your question is more of a request for feature development than a specific question, which is what this site focuses on. Have you tried anything yet?  If so, please show us what you've tried.  It will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Gesture detector `switch_action.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(Camera.this) {

        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            super.onSwipeRight();
            startActivity(new Intent(sampleActivity.this,Dashboard.class));
        }
    });`